# Umbraco XSLT for-each loop with variable

Tags: variables, xslt, parameters, umbraco

I have a XSL macro looks like this:
The same macro should be called from 2 different places only differenc is in the for-each sellect where "quickLinksUrls1" or "quickLinksUrls2" should be called.
I was thinking about sending that as a variable, but dont't know how to use this parameter in the for each.

How to achieve this without making two different macros with almost identical foreach loops?

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:param name="quickLinksGroup" select="/macro/quickLinksGroup"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*/Home/quickLinksUrls1/multi-url-picker/*">
        <xsl:variable name="nodeId" select="node-id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="linkTitle" select="link-title"/>

        <xsl:if test="number($nodeId) &gt; 0">
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have shown a bit of your input file, easier to not misunderstand.
Anyway, I take a shot at guessing what you're trying to do.

Just use the template match pattern instead of the `<xsl:for-each>`.

```
<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*/Home/*[name()= 'quickLinksUrl1' or name()='quickLinksUrl2']/multi-url-picker/*"/>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- The content of your initial "for-each" statement -->
        ...
</xsl:template>
```

And if you need to differentiate the templates body between quickLinksUrl1&2, you could use an `<xsl:if>` insinde the `template` or even in the `match` attribute.

In general, one should prefer using the template pattern and limit the usage of the `for-each` to simple cases. It's a good trick to keep in mind, imho.